# Archive data before deleting from table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, mariadb

I have case where I have to archive data of a table in other table before deleting it.

Lets say, I have user table and it's archive table as user_archive, which is created using same signature as user with only table name changed in following function:

```
def create_all_archive(db, bind="__all__", operation="create_all", skip_tables=False):
    """Create archive for all the tables

    :param db: Database connection
    :param app: Current application for which to create tables
    :param bind: Database bind
    :param operation: Operation, default "create_all"
    :param skip_tables: True if to be skipped else False
    :return:
    """
    app = db.get_app()
    if bind == '__all__':
        binds = [None] + list(app.config.get('SQLALCHEMY_BINDS') or ())
    elif isinstance(bind, string_types) or bind is None:
        binds = [bind]
    else:
        binds = bind

    for bind in binds:
        extra = {}
        if not skip_tables:
            tables = db.get_tables_for_bind(bind)
            tables_copy = [copy.deepcopy(table) for  table in tables]
            for table in tables_copy:
                table.name = "{}_archive".format(table.name)
            extra['tables'] = tables_copy
        op = getattr(db.Model.metadata, operation)
        op(bind=db.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
```

I called this function along with db.create_all() during start of an application, as follows:

```
def create_tables(db):
    """Creates all the schema tables as defined in models

    :param db: database connection
    :return:
    """
    db.create_all()
    create_all_archive(db)
```

My user delete member function is as follows:

```
def delete_user(self):
    """Delete user

    :return: Deleted user
    """
    import copy
    user = copy.deepcopy(self)
    user.__tablename__ = self.__archive_tablename__
    db.session.delete(self)
    session_commit()
    db.session.add(user)
    session_commit()

    return self
```

Here I am using deep copy to copy entire user object into another object and then changing the name of the table as above. But when The user is added to the session and then commit is called, it does not give any error but do not even store the value of `user` in `user_archive` table.

`__archive_tablename__` is a `declared_attr` which I am having inside a mixin to give archive table name as follows:

```
class ArchiveMixin(object):
    """Mixin class to add history table and perform operations on history table
    """
    @declared_attr
    def __archive_tablename__(cls):
        return "{}_archive".format(cls.__tablename__.lower())
```

Is this even possible? If yes, then what am I missing here?

> **NOTE:** I know a way out of all this by using two different database sessions, one for live data and another for archive data and
>   have same table definitions work in both the sessions. But in that
>   case archive data will be in completely different database. I
>   wanted it to be in same database. So, will it possible?

**Database Used:** MariaDB

Comment: Setting `__tablename__` on an instance should have no effect and obviously doesn't. It is just used during creation of a mapped class to create the `__table__`. Depending on what DB you're using this would be somewhat trivial to implement with triggers. With SQLAlchemy you might be able to emit additional `INSERT` statements in a [before delete](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.before_delete) event handler. Note that mapper-level events have strict limits on what they can do.

Comment: Thanks @lljaEverila. I am using MariaDB as database.

Comment: In that case see [the first trigger example here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/trigger-examples/), which is titled "Logging deletions". That should give you some ideas, if you were to take the trigger route.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Looks like using triggers for delete and update will be a better choice. Thanks.